# Npm scripts command not behaving like on shell

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, zsh

I'm trying to concatenate an arbitrary number of Javascript files into one big one.

I have the following command declared in the scripts part of my `package.json`

```
"js:dev": "uglifyjs inz/js/**/*.js > 'ouz/haz/js/main.js'"
```

When I run `npm run js:dev` the file gets written, but always with empty content.
If however I run the following directly on my shell (which is zsh) the expected contents get written into the file:

```
node_modules/uglifyjs/bin/uglifyjs inz/js/**/*.js > 'ouz/haz/js/main.js'
```

Why is this? I would expect both ways to behave the same. Is file globbing working differently in the context of `npm run`?

Comment: I bet `**` isn't supported there.

Comment: That's the most reasonable explanation. Would be a bummer though. Any workarounds?

Comment: `find inz/js -type f -name '*.js' -exec uglifyjs {} + >ouz/haz/js/main.js`

Comment: awesome :)  learn something new every day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet `**` isn't supported there.

`find inz/js -type f -name '*.js' -exec uglifyjs {} + >ouz/haz/js/main.js`
                    – 4ae1e1